# change item-left-edit into item-right-edit into Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, css, ionic-framework

Sorry if my question feel strange, I'm a beginner in Ionic framework.

I put a `show-delete="true"` on my ion-list and a ion-delete-button.
This is working great.

But now I want this button to be on the right.

When I take a look at the generated code, all classes are `"item-left-edit"` and `"item-left-editable"`.

I'd like to generate the `"item-right-edit"` and `"item-right-editable"`.

I don't find any information about theses generated classes in docs... If anyone have an idea how should I proceed ?

Edit : here is the piece of code:

```
 <ion-list show-delete="true" side="right">
                <ion-item ng-repeat="task in activeProject.tasks" class="item-right-editable">
                    {{task.title}} 

                       <ion-delete-button class="ion-android-cancel" ng-click="deleteTask($index)"></ion-delete-button>

                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
```

Comment: Can you show some code? maybe create a fiddle for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something by modifiyng the ionic.bundle.js file like this :

```
    var ITEM_TPL_DELETE_BUTTON =
  '<div class="item-right-edit item-delete enable-pointer-events">' +
  '</div>';
```

instead of

```
var ITEM_TPL_DELETE_BUTTON =
  '<div class="item-left-edit item-delete enable-pointer-events">' +
  '</div>';
```

Anyway, i was wondering if there where more "proper" way to do that...

Comment: it still doing some padding on other side.

Answer (score 0):

also use

> $element.children().toggleClass('list-right-editing', isShown);

instead of

> $element.children().toggleClass('list-left-editing', isShown);

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue and what I did was this...

I grabbed the styles from the `.item-right-edit` class and all its children added the prefix class I wanted to invert the behavior like `.my-class .item-right-edit`, then added a missing style, which was `left: 0;` to the main `.item-right-edit` class and finally I renamed the class to `.item-left-edit`.

The downside of this is that we'll have a class called `.item-left-edit` that will actually behave as `.item-right-edit` class, but adding the specific class prefix won't interfere with other parts of the app.

I leave here the CSS I used to switch over the behavior:

```
.my-class .item-left-edit {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  padding-left: 20px;
  left: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(75px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(75px, 0, 0); }
  .my-class .item-left-edit .button {
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 100%; }
    .my-class .item-left-edit .button.icon {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -moz-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 32px; }
  .my-class .item-left-edit.visible {
    display: block; }
    .my-class .item-left-edit.visible.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
```

Hope this helps :)